# How can the System databases in SQL Server 2016 be moved using Powershell?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, powershell, smo, dbatools

I'm trying to move the system databases using Powershell ie. **without** using any T-SQL.

1. Using SMO : 
   `Install-Module SQL-SMO 
   $smo = New-SMO -ServerName localhost
   $smo.databases["TempDB"].PrimaryFilePath= "F:\Tempdb\"
   $smo.databases["TempDB"].Alter()`    gives an error:

   > 'PrimaryFilePath' is a ReadOnly property.

The logfile moves fine though. 
`$smo.databases["TempDB"].LogFiles[0].Filename = "F:\Tempdb\tempdb.ldf"`

2. Couldn't locate any specific cmdlets in the SQLServer or DBATools modules either. `Copy-DbaDatabase` comes closest; but not exactly.

Comment: "I'm trying to move the system databases using Powershell ie. without using any T-SQL." Why?

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft , 
1. The rest of my Azure Infrastructure deployment script is in Powershell. 
2. I'm an IT Pro; not adept at T-SQL.
3. Microsoft is enabling Powershell to manage all its products.

Comment: Yep.  That's the good reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While not completely answering your question about moving **ALL** system databases with Powershell, I did want to provide a working example of moving the individual files for `TEMPDB`.

Let's assume the current location of your `TEMPDB` files is

`C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL13.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA`

and you want to move them to

`C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL13.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\TempDB`

You basically have to iterate through the `filegroups` and then the `files` within the `filegroups`.

Then, you do the same type of action against your log files.

```
Install-Module SQL-SMO
$smo = New-SMO -ServerName localhost
$TempDb = $smo.databases["TempDB"]

foreach ($fg in $TempDb.FileGroups) {
    foreach ($fl in $fg.Files) {
    $fl.FileName = $fl.FileName.Replace("C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL13.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA","C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL13.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\TempDB")
    }
}

foreach ($fg in $TempDb.FileGroups) {
    foreach ($fl in $fg.Files) {
    $fl.FileName
    }
}

foreach ($fl in $TempDb.LogFiles) {
    $fl.FileName = $fl.FileName.Replace("C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL13.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA","C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL13.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\TempDB")
    }

$smo.databases["TempDB"].Alter()
```

---

After restarting your SQL Server instance, you should see the `TEMPDB` files being allocated under the new directory.

---

After posting my original answer, I did a little more research on moving SQL Server system databases using `POWERSHELL` and found a very detailed post related to moving the `master` database.

[Moving your Master Database with #Powershell](http://www.mikefal.net/2015/12/09/moving-your-master-database-with-powershell/).

Answer (score 1):

The `Restore-DbaDatabase` in dbatools right now blocks the ability to restore the system databases. It is on the roadmap at some point to work out the process. The block in that command is why Copy-DbaDatabase would fail as well, and you can't move any system database by simple detach/attach method.

Overall it could be worked out to perform the whole task in PowerShell using dbatools commands with a mix of just "manually prepared" code around SMO.

Comment: Which property of the TempDB should one edit to move it?

Answer (score 0):

`$smo = New-SMO -ServerName localhost -Verbose`

`$('model','MSDB','TempDB')|
        ForEach-Object {$Db = $smo.databases[$PSItem]
                foreach ($fg in $Db.FileGroups) 
                        {foreach ($fl in $fg.Files) {$fl.FileName = $fl.FileName.Replace("C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL14.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA","F:\SystemDB")}}
                foreach ($fl in $Db.LogFiles) {$fl.FileName = $fl.FileName.Replace("C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL14.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA","F:\SystemDB")}
                $smo.databases[$PSItem].Alter()
                        }`

`Stop-Service -Name MSSQLSERVER -Force -Verbose`

`$('model','MSDB','mast')|ForEach-Object {Move-Item -Path $('C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL14.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\'+$PSItem+'*') -Destination F:\SystemDB\ -Verbose}`

`$wmisvc = $(New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Wmi.ManagedComputer 'localhost').Services | where {$_.name -eq "MSSQLSERVER"}
$wmisvc.StartupParameters= '-dF:\SystemDB\master.mdf;-eF:\SystemDB\ERRORLOG;-lF:\SystemDB\mastlog.ldf'
$wmisvc.Alter()`

`Start-Service -Name MSSQLSERVER,SQLSERVERAGENT -Verbose`

This moves all the System databases.